# Objective-C arrays, style and spirit

Tags: objective-c

Newbie question.  Looking at arrays (ie: dynamically sized) this works:

```
NSArray *array;
array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     @"one", @"two", nil];
```

This does not:

```
array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     1, 2, nil];
```

Ok, I get it.  This works:

```
array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], nil];
```

Its sorta less "on the fly" as C++ / Java.  I see the same thing with the init examples I'm reading.  For example:

```
// pseudo objc example
MyVar v = [MyVar init];  // blank
[v setSomething];
[v setSomethingElse];
// use v down here
```

In C++/Java I'd do:

```
MyVar v = new MyVar("foo", "bar", "baz", "quux");
```

And I'd know that v is ready to go by default.  Is there a spirit of ObjC that I should not fight?  Should I just expect to write more lines and less "one-liners"?

Comment: Autoboxing scalars in Java is actually a relatively new language feature... you can also use the new pointer arrays to store scalars in Obj-C, but you'll have to take care of allocating and freeing the storage for them properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objective-C, the "init" method is just a method. Unlike Java or C++ whose constructors are different than other methods. So you can define your own init methods that behave like C++ or Java constructors. For example, you could define an init method that takes several parameters. It might look something like this.

```
MyVar* v = [[MyVar alloc] initWithName:@"foo" andTitle:@"bar"];
// do something with v
[v release];
```

Common practice is to simply create new methods that perform object initialization, and prefix the method name with "init" for clarity and consistency.

Comment: Objective-C style does eschew the use of the word "and" in method names. That would normally be initWithName:title:.

Answer (score 2):

What you get with Objective-C's verbosity is greater readability.

Sure, while you're writing code, it might be easy to knock up something like you wrote

```
MyRect rect = new MyRect(1.0, 1.0, 3.0 3.0);
```

But when you, or more likely someone else, comes to maintain your code then I would argue that this is much easier to read:

```
MyRect *rect = [[MyRect alloc] initWithX:1.0 Y:1.0 width:3.0 height:3.0];
```

And in these days of smart editors it isn't that much harder to write.

Answer (score 2):

`NSArray`, its modifiable variant `NSMutableArray`, and all collection structures (`NSDictionary`, `NSSet`) are made for storing objects. This is why you see `[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]` instead of simply `1`.

For strings, note that an Objective-c string (like `@"one"`, including leading `@`) is an object of type `NSString`, whereas a C string (like `"one"`, without `@`) is not an object.

If you want the simplicity of storing simple values in arrays, don't forget that Objective-C is a superset of C. This means that you can use a declaration like:

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write constructors that take named parameters to get it down to one line:

```
MyVar *v = [[MyVar alloc] initWithFoo:@"foo" bar:@"bar" baz:@"baz" quux:@"quux"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Objective-C is pretty verbose, so you're going to need to get used to that.

The `MyVar init` case is not quite right; you generally need to do a `[[MyVar alloc] init]` or a `[MyVar new]`. And in many cases, there are `init` variants that take arguments, like

```
MyVar v = [[MyVar alloc] initWithSomething: "foo" somethingElse: "bar"];
```

If you want something less verbose, where you can get more one liners in, you might want to look into [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/), which is a binding between Ruby and Objective-C that gives you access to all of the Cocoa APIs but with a much more compact, high level syntax (and you can go even more compact still with [HotCocoa](http://www.macruby.org/hotcocoa.html). Of course, there is a bit of a performance penalty using MacRuby, so if you're doing a high performance game it might not be ideal to write your drawing loop in RubyCocoa, but its fine for the vast majority of applications.